# Exception stacktrace of Reflected method in Java

Tags: java, reflection, stack-trace

I am calling a method via reflection , which throws an exception.

However when I get the stacktrace via

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

i don't get the entire stack trace upto the reflected method. It gets the stack trace only uptil my method which implements reflection.

The reflected class is in a different project altogether.

EDIT : Adding code snippet

**Project A**

```
Class ReflectionImpl {

   public void callMethodsviaReflection{
     try{
              // Reflection code to call the method

         }catch(InvocationTargetException iTE){

           StringBuilder errorLogBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            errorLogBuilder.append(ex.toString());
            errorLogBuilder.append("\n");

            StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

             for (int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {

                 errorLogBuilder.append((elements[i].toString()));
                 errorLogBuilder.append("\n");
             }

            System.out.println(errorLogBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Project B** --> **References Project A in Eclipse**

```
Class ReflectedClass{

 List<String> nameList = null;

 public void reflectedMethod(){

     nameList.add("Hello");
    }      
}
```

Comment: 'reflected class is in a different project altogether.', may be thats the reason

Comment: but even though it is in a different project, it is being referenced in Eclipse.

Comment: It's not at all clear *where* you're getting the stack trace. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it much clearer.

Comment: Your reflected method has returned via exception and thus should not be on the stack anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the particular point where you are calling:

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

your 'reflective invocation' has already been completed, which is reflected in the call stack you get back from the call. Sounds more like you want:

```
iTE.getCause().getStackTrace();
```

Which will give you the call stack ***up to and including*** the method that actually threw the exception.